# How to find the error details for an SSRS Data Driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-subscription

I have a report in SSRS and I scheduled it to trigger via data driven subscription. After the schedule, I got the status as **Done: 3 processed of 5 total; 2 errors.**

But now I want to know the details of those failed 2 errors? Is there a way to find the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not specified otherwise, the SSRS log files can be found here:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

where `%ProgramFiles%` is the language specific name of the program files folder and `MSSQL.x` takes into account the components installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the specific details for the 2 failed reports. But your answer is unclear. Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @Akhil  Everything SSRS does is logged in the files at the location in my answer.  Open up the relevant file and look for the errors.

Comment: So your are talking about the file path that is in the server location? If yes then I do not have access for the server location.

Comment: @Akhil  Then you will need to speak with your DBA, or run the report manually for all the values in your data driven subscription and wait until one of them errors.

Comment: My folder path starts %Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS... That is, MSRS instead of MSSQL.